# Merge Two Dataframes by Index without loosing data on empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

say I want to merge two dataframes on a matching index using pandas, but one of the df's is missing some indexes, how could I do this without losing any data?
E.g.

```
            price  
21-02-2022  2 
22-02-2022  1 
23-02-2022  3 

            sales  
22-02-2022  2
```

should output:

```
            price  sales
21-02-2022  2      0
22-02-2022  1      2
23-02-2022  3      0
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the noob question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.merge(df2, how='left',
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
            price   sales
21-02-2022      2       0
22-02-2022      1       2
23-02-2022      3       0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called an **outer join**, which you can achieve as follows:

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Notably, you must `fillna` as pandas, by default, will put in `NaN` values for non-matching rows.

Comment: Note that if you have existing NAs in `df2`, this will fill them, which my be unwanted. In such case, `reindex` `df2` with a `fill_value=0` prior to `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat them together on `axis=1`

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            price  sales
21-02-2022      2      0
22-02-2022      1      2
23-02-2022      3      0
```